# How Do I Invoke Berkeley Database 1.85 Compatibility Mode Under CentOS 5?

Tags: centos, centos5, yum, berkeleydb

I have been trying to work with databases that were created under Berkeley Database 1.85 so that I can convert them to MySQL.

I believe the files are Berkeley DB 1.85 under CentOS 5 for the following reasons:

```
bash-3.2$ file comment.db
comment.db: Berkeley DB 1.85/1.86 (Btree, version 3, big-endian)

bash-3.2$ uname -r
2.6.18-128.el5
```

I know that there is a Berkeley DB 1.85 Compatibility Mode, but I am not sure how to put it into effect.

When I run:

```
bash-3.2$ yum list installed
```

... I get the following results, among others:

```
compat-db.i386                       4.2.52-5.1                        installed

db4.i386                             4.3.29-10.el5_5.2                 installed
db4-devel.i386                       4.3.29-10.el5_5.2                 installed
db4-java.i386                        4.3.29-10.el5_5.2                 installed
db4-tcl.i386                         4.3.29-10.el5_5.2                 installed
db4-utils.i386                       4.3.29-10.el5_5.2                 installed
```

Are these the yum modules that we need to get Berkeley DB 1.85 Compatibility Mode to work?  Or are there others?

Is there some configuration that needs to be done in order for this mode to be active?

Does DB_File pickup Berkeley DB 1.85 Compatibility Mode automatically?

Comment: In [Configuring Berkeley DB](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17076_02/html/installation/build_unix_conf.html) it says there is an `--enable-compat185` option.

I suspect that, in order to access it, I will have to compile from sources.

Answer (score 1):

The `db4_utils` package contains `db_dump185`, which you can use to dump a DB 1.85 format database. You can send its output to `db_load` to load it into a current format database.

Comment: Yes, except that is not working in this case.  What we want to do is to enable the application that created the databases to operate.  It is written in Perl and based on the DB_File Perl module.